# How to get pid of the process that run in background exec by shell in php

Tags: php, linux, bash, shell

I'm working on a shell in php, and I want to display the same output as bash. When in bash you execute `sleep 10 &` you'll get `[1] <PID>`. How can I do the same in php, when I call shell using:

```
    if (preg_match("/&\s*$/", $command)) {
        $this->$shell_fn($token, '/bin/bash -c ' . escapeshellarg($command) .
                         " > /dev/null");
        return array(
            'output' => '',
            'cwd' => $path
        );
    }
```

$shell_fn is variable that point to wrapper over shell_exec, exec or cgi script called by curl. Is it even possible to get the pid from php or using a shell?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want the pid in [bash](/questions/tagged/bash), you can do use the [`!` special parameter](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Special-Parameters) to get the pid of the most recently backgrounded process:

```
bash -c 'sleep 10 & echo $!'
```

I don't know exactly how [php](/questions/tagged/php) spawns external processes, but I imagine you'd be able to capture the `echo` output here, just by running the above shell command.

Comment: This work: `echo shell_exec("/bin/bash -c 'sleep 5 > /dev/null & echo $!'");`

Comment: do you know how to get that `[1]` number?

Comment: This is the job number.  You can use the `jobs` command to get it.  Something like this in your case: `/bin/bash -c 'sleep 5 > /dev/null & jobs -l | grep $!'`

Comment: Or more accurately `/bin/bash -c 'sleep 5 > /dev/null & jobs -l | grep -w $!'`, i.e. pass `-w` to grep.

Answer (score 1):

I use this functions to manage process:

```
function ProcessStart($cmdline) // return pid
{
    exec( "nohup $cmdline >/dev/null 2>&1 & echo $!", $output) ;
    // print_r ($output);
    return (int)$output[0];
}

function ProcessStatus($pid) // return TRUE (live) o FALSE (dead)
{
    exec("ps -p $pid",$output);
    // print_r($output);
    return ( isset($output[1]) ? TRUE : FALSE ) ;
}

function ProcessStop($pid)
{
    exec("kill $pid",$output); // kill -9 ??
}
```